# errorbar plot against datetime fails

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib, errorbar

Errorbar plotting does not always work when the `x` axis is a `datetime`:

```
z = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp': {0: pd.Timestamp('2018-06-16 04:33:27'),
  1: pd.Timestamp('2018-06-16 18:07:40')},
 'average': {0: 1.4158309812874796, 1: 1.4293226152856995},
 'stdev': {0: 0.5721450460404708, 1: 0.5771658975429514}})
```

Now `z` is

```
            timestamp   average     stdev
0 2018-06-16 04:33:27  1.415831  0.572145
1 2018-06-16 18:07:40  1.429323  0.577166
```

`plt.plot(z.timestamp, z.average)` works as expected, 
but `plt.errorbar(z.timestamp, z.average, yerr=z.stdev)` produces

```
<ErrorbarContainer object of 3 artists>
Error in callback <function install_repl_displayhook.<locals>.post_execute at 0x7fe251344840> (for post_execute):


Truncated Traceback (Use C-c C-x to view full TB):
~/.virtualenvs/algorisk/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/dates.py in viewlim_to_dt(self)
   1024                              'often happens if you pass a non-datetime '
   1025                              'value to an axis that has datetime units'
-> 1026                              .format(vmin))
   1027         return num2date(vmin, self.tz), num2date(vmax, self.tz)
   1028 

ValueError: view limit minimum -7.64586229992263e+16 is less than 1 and is an invalid Matplotlib date value. This often happens if you pass a non-datetime value to an axis that has datetime units
```

What am I doing wrong?

PS. Other values seem to work. E.g.,

```
plt.errorbar(np.array([datetime.datetime(2018,7,30,12),
            datetime.datetime(2018,7,30,15)]).astype("datetime64[h]"),
         np.array([2,3]),
         yerr=np.array([1,2]))
```

works as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Natively, matplotlib can plot numpy arrays. Instead of providing pandas `Series` to the plotting function you probably want to provide the underlying numpy arrays, obtained via `.values`.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp': {0: pd.Timestamp('2018-06-16 04:33:27'),
                                1: pd.Timestamp('2018-06-16 18:07:40')},
                  'average': {0: 1.4158309812874796, 1: 1.4293226152856995},
                  'stdev': {0: 0.5721450460404708, 1: 0.5771658975429514}})

plt.errorbar(df.timestamp.values, df.average.values, yerr=df.stdev.values)

plt.show()
```

Comment: thanks, using `timestamp.values` solved it -- however, do you have an idea _why_ it is sometimes necessary? why does the error mean?

Comment: I wouldn't care too much about the error. Essentially the timestamp is converted to a number, which is not in the format that matplotlib requires for datetimes. This is due to the `Series` being used. Simply consider the fact that you may often use `Series` in matplotlib an implementation detail, I does not mean that they are officially supported.

Comment: tbh, I am shocked by the fact that something may work with `s.values` but not with `s` and this is not considered a bug.

Comment: The fact that library A does not take library B's object as input would only ever be a bug if library A claimed that to be possible. Pandas is not a dependency of matplotlib. This makes it not straight forward to test every possible combination of pandas objects and matplotlib plotting functions. There is a tendency to convert any pandas object to a numpy array internally, but that is still work in progress. So far you need to do the conversion yourself which is pretty easy.